# How to set the formula to the sum of a column in c# interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

How to set the formula to the sum of a column in c# interop ?

I tried

```
sheet.Range["O4"].Formula = string.Format("=SUM({0})", table.ListColumns["MONTANT"].DataBodyRange.Address);
```

But when i add a row to the table the sum is not correct, It does not take the new line.

Comment: Could you try `"=SUM({0}:{0})"` format instead?

Comment: perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sum a column in Excel, say, `AX`, you write `SUM(AX:AX)`. Therefore, the format should be `SUM({0}:{0})`:

```
sheet.Range["O4"].Formula = string.Format("=SUM({0}:{0})", table.ListColumns["MONTANT"].DataBodyRange.Address);
```